# Code works in VC++ 6 but not in VS2013

Tags: c++

We have DLL generated in VC++ 6.0 which creates XML file containing Log data. Now on migration of source code to VS2013, the same function creates XMl file but doesn't fetch log data in generated xml. 
There is a reference of #include 'msxml3.dll' in VC6 source code. Does that create a problem while running and building DLL on VS2013

Comment: What debugging have you done?  You must be prepared to debug the code if you're going to do a migration from a pre ANSI C++ compiler to one that is standard conforming.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'd slap some huge quotes on that "standard-conforming", but your point holds. OT: maybe I just don't know the MSVC platform well enough, but this question looks like it lacks any information that could lead to a definitive answer.

Comment: VS 2013 is standard conforming in that it has a written document to adhere to.  Yes there are things that are not implemented, but at least, there is a reference point it has to consider.  The VC 6.0 compiler had no such document (maybe a draft of C++ 98), thus is not even C++ 98 compliant.

Comment: To the OP -- you are jumping over 5 versions of Visual C++.  That in itself is not a bad thing, but you have to realize that there is a good bet that something will not work correctly and you have to just roll up your sleeves and debug the issue.  Maybe you had an existing bug in your code and the new compiler exposed it.  You won't know until you do some debugging.